# VisualStateManager: Setting Panel.ZIndex

Tags: wpf, xaml

**Why can't I set Panel.ZIndex within a VisualStateManager?**

I am building a carousel user interface and am struggling to find out why I am unable to set a value for Panel.ZIndex.

This XAML is embedded within a VisualState element:

```
<Storyboard>
    <VisualState>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Rectangle.(Panel.ZIndex)">

            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TargetProperty` is not set correctly.

Try this instead.

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="ZIndexChanged">
                <Storyboard>
                    <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle">
                        <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4"/>
                    </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: But note that it's `Canvas.ZIndex` in Silverlight, but `Panel.ZIndex` in WPF.

Comment: Ohh sorry you just need to replace Canvas with Panel then. But maybe also replace the key frames to the Int32 one?

Comment: Also another thing I just noticed, the `VisualState` tags should wrap the `Storyboard` ones, not the other way around. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! So ObjectAnnimationUsingKeyFrames only apply to actual objects.

Answer (score 1):

I also learned from the previous answer that I can resolve the animation like this:

```
  <Int32Animation    Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                        To="4"
                        Duration="0:0:.15">
    </Int32Animation>
```